# Problems with a HFS+ hdd on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, hfs+

I have a 2TB Western Digital HDD with one partition formatted as HFS+.
I tried pretty much everything to make it *readable* (not even writable) from Ubuntu Server, but had no success.

I tried:

- changing my linux uid to 501
- installing `hfsprogs` and `hfsplus`
- disabling journaling from OSX Disk Utility

I'm blocked.

The root problems seems to be that linux isn't able to read a partition table on the hard drive: when I run `sudo fdisk -l`, it tells me that

> `/dev/sdc` doesn't contain a valid partition table

That said, I'm obviously not able to `mount` anything since the OS only knows about `/dev/sdc`, no partitions like `/dev/sdc1`.

How can I proceed? I have access to an OSX machine at all times if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding hfsutils, hfsutils-tcltk, libhfsp-dev, and maybe tmfs will bring in some dependency that will help with your situation:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsutils hfsutils-tcltk libhfsp-dev tmfs
```

Comment: No luck here. Seems like there's some problem with partition tables.